# Получить результирующий массив из объектов массива

Tags: массивы, функции, объекты

Задача.
Написать функцию getAllPropValues(arr, prop), которая получает массив объектов и имя ключа, возвращает массив значений определенного поля prop из каждого объекта в массиве.
Ниже незавершенный. Интересует несложный вариант решения (для начального осваивания js), который не выходит за рамки использования функций, массивов, объектов.

```
const users = [
  { name: 'Poly', age: 7, mood: 'happy' },
  { name: 'Mango', age: 4, mood: 'blissful'},
  { name: 'Ajax', age: 3, mood: 'tired' }
];

function getAllPropValues(arr, prop) {
  for ( let i = 0; i < users.length; i += 1 ) {
    let arr = Object.entries(users[i]);

    users[i] = arr;

    const index = users[i][0].indexOf(prop);
    let newArr = [];

    newArr.push(users[i][0][1]);

    console.log(newArr);
  }

  return newArr;
}


// Вызовы функции для проверки
console.log(
  getAllPropValues(users, 'name')
); // ['Poly', 'Mango', 'Ajax']

console.log(
  getAllPropValues(users, 'mood')
); // ['happy', 'blissful', 'tired']

console.log(
  getAllPropValues(users, 'active')
); // []
```

Comment: каким образом для последнего примера получился пустой массив?

Comment: Проверка функции входила в условия задачи. Понимаю, что active нет в объекте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения одного массива на основе другого можно использовать метод [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Данный метод позволяет отобразить каждый элемент старого массива на новый. В данном случае каждому элементу старого массива ставится значение указанного свойства.

Таким образом код может принять вид:

```
function getAllPropValues(arr, prop) {
  return arr.map(el => el[prop]);
}
```

---

```js
const users = [{
    name: 'Poly',
    age: 7,
    mood: 'happy'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mango',
    age: 4,
    mood: 'blissful'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ajax',
    age: 3,
    mood: 'tired'
  }
];

function getAllPropValues(arr, prop) {
  return arr.map(el => el[prop]);
}


// Вызовы функции для проверки
console.log(
  getAllPropValues(users, 'name')
); // ['Poly', 'Mango', 'Ajax']

console.log(
  getAllPropValues(users, 'mood')
); // ['happy', 'blissful', 'tired']

console.log(
  getAllPropValues(users, 'active')
); // []
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const users = [
  { name: 'Poly', age: 7, mood: 'happy' },
  { name: 'Mango', age: 4, mood: 'blissful'},
  { name: 'Ajax', age: 3, mood: 'tired' }
];

function getAllPropValues(arr, prop) {
  return arr.reduce(function(result, item) {
    if (result.indexOf(item[prop]) == -1 && // if need unique values
        typeof item[prop] != "undefined")   // if don't want undefined's
      result.push(item[prop]);
    return result;
  }, []);
}

console.log(getAllPropValues(users, 'name'));
console.log(getAllPropValues(users, 'mood'));
console.log(getAllPropValues(users, 'active'));
```